# How to add missing values to a string column using SimpleImputer()?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am having a dataset which I read into a pandas dataframe.
Most of them are string columns.
Column structure of my dataframe:

```
['id', 'currently working', column3, column4, ....]
```

The column that has missing data is `'currently working'`. The column contains only two values -> `YES`, `NO` and there are `null` values as well.

I applied the SimpleImputer() in one of my previous learning and that is on an integer column which contain salaries, where I give `strategy` as `mean` to preprocess the dataset and replace `null`s like below.

```
imputer = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='mean')
```

But in my current scenario, the column is of `String` type which I certainly can't apply any numeric function methods.

Could anyone let me know how can I preprocess the existing data and replace `null`s in a string column of a pandas dataframe ?
What is the preprocessing method that should I follow when working on String columns ?

Comment: Noone can tell what you should follow, because these `null` values may actually be meaningful and not worth replacing

Comment: I would try to one-hot encode this column as 3 classes, namely yes/no/unknown

Comment: Yes, I have implemented the oneHotEncoding and the output has `None` apart from `YES` & `NO`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `most_frequent` strategy. [SimpleImputer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.SimpleImputer.html) will replace missing using the most frequent value. It may also be useful to use `add_indicatorbool=True`. In this case, the output of the imputer’s transform will stack an additional column with the value from the [MissingIndicator](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.MissingIndicator.html). So, your model will have a clue that the value was missing before.

Code example:

```
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer

imp = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, 
                    strategy='most_frequent', 
                    add_indicator=True)
```